# How to get pre-populated form using edit button

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get a pre-populated form using "edit" button that i'm using in my table. I've tried everything but i'm not able to get pre-populated form. I'm using only one form to add as well as edit.

this is my views.py edit function:

```
def edit_row(request, rowid):
    item = get_object_or_404(Studentapp, id=rowid)
    print item
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = EntryForm(request.POST, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            post=form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('studentapp:index'),rowid.id)
        else:
            form=EntryForm(instance=item)
        return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form})
    else:
        form=EntryForm(instance=item)
        return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form})
```

This is the form that i'm using:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class = "modal-content">
    <div class = "modal-header">
      <button type = "button" class = "close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h3 class="modal-title"><b>Add Student</b></h3>
    </div>
    <div class = "modal-body">
      <form action = "{% url 'studentapp:addstudent' %}" id="addform" method = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class = "form-group">
          <label for = "your_name">Your name: </label>
          <input class = "form-control" id="new_name" type = "text" name="name" value="{{ current_name }}" placeholder="Enter your name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for = "course_name">Course: </label>
          <input id="new_course" class = 'form-control' type = "text" name="course" value="{{ current_course }}" placeholder="Enter your course">
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group">
          <label for = "rollno">Roll No.: </label>
          <input id="new_rollno" type = "text" class = 'form-control' name="roll" value="{{ current_roll }}" placeholder="Enter your roll number">
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group">
          <label for ="addr">Address: </label>
          <textarea id="new_address" type = "text" name="address" class = 'form-control' value="{{ current_addr }}" placeholder="Enter your address"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type = "submit" value="Submit" class = "btn btn-success" style="font-size:18px;" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my forms.py:

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update(
    {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter your name'})
    self.fields['roll'].widget.attrs.update(
    {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter your roll'})
    self.fields['course'].widget.attrs.update(
    {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter your course'})
    self.fields['address'].widget.attrs.update(
    {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter your address'})

class Meta:
    model = Studentapp
    fields = ['name','roll','course','address']
```

Comment: Show your `GET` method in the `edit_row` view.

Comment: The values of the name attributes of your input elements in HTML are not matching with the field names in EntryForm. That can cause problems.

Comment: It's not working. I've tried GET method

Comment: "django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (your_name, course_name, addr, rollno) specified for Studentapp" it's showing this error in terminal if try to match the name attributes of input elements

Answer (score 0):

In your view pass the populated form when the request method is `GET`.

```
def edit_row(request, rowid):
    item = get_object_or_404(Studentapp, id=rowid)
    print item
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = EntryForm(request.POST, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            post=form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('studentapp:index'),rowid.id)
        else:
            form=EntryForm(instance=item)
        return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form})
    else:
        form=EntryForm(instance=item)
        return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form})
```

In your template don't bother to put all the rows manually, use form instead.

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

If you want to customize the style, you can iterate over the form and get the fields to show them when using your own design.

```
<form action="" id="addform" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for f in form %}
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label">{{ f.name }}</label>
        <div>{{ f }}</div>
    </div>

    <input type = "submit" value="Submit" class = "btn btn-success" style="font-size:18px;" />
</form>
```

And update the form to include your own style.

```
from django import forms
from studentapp.models import Studentapp

class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update(
        {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter your name'})
        self.fields['roll'].widget.attrs.update(
        {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter your roll'})
        self.fields['course'].widget.attrs.update(
        {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter your course'})
        self.fields['address'].widget.attrs.update(
        {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter your address'})

    class Meta:
        model = Studentapp
        fields = ['name','roll','course','address']
```

Comment: the main problem is in view and forms.py i'm still not able to get pre populated form

Comment: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'
i'm getting this error in terminal more often.

Comment: Make sure you have the `index.html` at right place.

Comment: Just update your template as I suggested and make sure it's in the right place.

Comment: no luck. form is not visible. there are no input fields

Comment: Did you put the `Meta` class inside your form ?

Comment: Yes it's there.

Comment: Edit your question with your latest template code. It should work if you did it correctly.

Comment: try removing url from the action in your form.

Comment: if i remove it i wont be able  to add a new student information then

Comment: i'm using the same form to add as well as edit the information of student. it's possible right?

Comment: Using same form ? Yes possible. But you should use two different url and view.

Comment: i'm using two different views. i can post my addstudent view. maybe that will help.

Comment: Do you get form pre-populated now ?

Comment: i'm just getting a blank form. shall i post my addstudent view?

Answer (score 0):

@MD. Khairul Basar's answer is the right way to do it, however if for some reason you want to put all the rows manually, the name attribute of the HTML input elements should match with the field names, see the changes below:

```
<div  class="modal fade" id="addform" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class = "modal-content">
        <div class = "modal-header">
          <button type = "button" class = "close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title"><b>Add Student</b></h3>
        </div>
        <div class = "modal-body">
          <form action = "{% url 'studentapp:addstudent' %}" id="addform" method = "POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class = "form-group">
              <label for = "your_name">Your name: </label>
              <input class = "form-control" id="new_name" type = "text" name="name" value="{{ current_name }}" placeholder="Enter your name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for = "course_name">Course: </label>
              <input id="new_course" class = 'form-control' type = "text" name="course" value="{{ current_course }}" placeholder="Enter your course">
            </div>
            <div class = "form-group">
              <label for = "rollno">Roll No.: </label>
              <input id="new_rollno" type = "text" class = 'form-control' name="roll" value="{{ current_roll }}" placeholder="Enter your roll number">
            </div>
            <div class = "form-group">
              <label for ="addr">Address: </label>
              <textarea id="new_address" type = "text" name="address" class = 'form-control' value="{{ current_addr }}" placeholder="Enter your address"></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type = "submit" value="Submit" class = "btn btn-success" style="font-size:18px;" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```